# Change multiple author reference from '&' to 'and' with natbib bibliography

Tags: natbib

I'd like to change the separation between multiple article/book authors from '&' to 'and' in natbib.
 eg:

```
@book{lee2009global,
  title={{Global Marketing Management}},
  author={Lee, K. and Carter, S.},
  isbn={9780199239429},
  lccn={2009005337},
  comment={http://books.google.com/books?id=ZBkPOQAACAAJ},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
```

then:

```
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

\citep{lee2009global}
```

produces:

```
 (Lee & Carter, 2009)
```

I'd like it to produce:

```
 (Lee and Carter, 2009)
```

Comment: what bibliography style?

Comment: I've currently selected agsm, but it's not fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the following in your document preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\harvardand}{and}}
```

This is not a general solution for all `.bst` files, but it will work for at least two  of the ones that are built into `natbib`: `agsm` and `dcu`.

For other `.bst` files, the solution may involve modifying the `.bst` file itself.

If you need a generic `.bst` file that fits your need you can make one using the `makebst`. (From a command line prompt, enter `latex makebst`).

Alternatively, if you are just beginning to use `bibtex` you should check out the `biblatex` package, which has many advantages over `natbib` with respect to your ability to tweak the output yourself.