# Changing '&' to 'og' in citations between names when using apacite package

Tags: citing, memoir, languages, apa-style

When I use the `\citet` command, it makes a the `&` sign between the names. It is not supposed to do that, it is supposed to spell out 'and', which is the correct style for in-text citation. However, I have a further problem, which is that I write in Danish, and I need it to spell out 'og' between the names instead of and. I have been trying to find a danish.apc file, or to create one myself from the swedish.apc file. So far, I have been unsuccessful in both. I tried the solution suggested on a similar issue, where someone was writing in catalan: [Change citation conjunction from "and" to "i"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109221/change-citation-conjunction-from-and-to-i)

The solution there suggested here, however, does not yield an acceptable result because the commands do not do what is written that they do.
The `\renewcommand{\BBAA}{&}` is supposed to change only the text in the references and between parantheses, that is, using the `\citep` command. But it also changes it within the text when using the `\citet`command. The `\renewcommand{\BBAB}{og}` command does nothing.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\BBAA}{&}
\renewcommand{\BBAB}{og}
\begin{document}
\section{Citations}
If I cite \citet{smiths} using the '\citet' command then I get an \& sign rather than 'og'. Of course without it affecting the \citep command and writing 'og' within the parantheses instead of the correct sign \& \citep{smiths}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}

Reference in the bib document:
@article{smiths,
author = {Smith, A. and Smith, B.},
journal = {Journal of Apacite},
number = {1},
pages = {24305--36811},
title = {{How do I change \& to 'and'}},
volume = {1},
year = {2014}
}
```

Comment: It is, is `biblatex` an option for you?

Comment: I don't understand: do you want that in `\citet` the & becomes “og” and in `\citep` it remains &?

Comment: @egreg - The APA requires that `&` be used for parenthetical citations (à la `\citep`) and in the bibliography entries, whereas `and` (or `og`, or `i`, ...) must be used for textual citations (à la `\citet`).

Comment: @Mico APA requirements are stupid; the & symbol is good for a company name, not for citations.

Comment: @egreg - I fully agree with your evaluation of this requirement. But what choice does a wretched soul have if if he/she must meet these requirements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you make the following two changes to your code:

- First, change

  ```
  \usepackage{apacite}
  \usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
  ```

  This loads the `natbib` package in a way that maintains compatibility with `apacite`. (For more on this, see p. 7 of the user guide of the `apacite` package.) Using this loading method has the added benefit that `natbib` is loaded automatically with the option `longnamesfirst` (see p. 15 of the user guide). In short, don't load the two packages independently.
- Second, change `\renewcommand{\BBAA}{&}` to `\renewcommand{\BBAA}{\&}`, i.e., be sure to "escape" the `&` symbol.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} %% just to keep everything on one page
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{smiths,
author = {Smith, A. and Smith, B.},
journal = {Journal of Apacite},
number = {1},
pages = {24305--36811},
title = {How do {I} change \& to `and'},
volume = {1},
year = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} % <-- new
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\renewcommand{\BBAA}{\&} % <-- modified
\renewcommand{\BBAB}{og}

\begin{document}
\citet{smiths}

\citep{smiths}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Faergen - Thank you for posting a very clear MWE. That's what made it straightforward to spot the problems and come up with solutions.