# how to change the language of the "and" conjunction in a citation call-out?

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

i'm using `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` for my bibliography, but as i am brazilian, i'd like to change the `and` when using `\citet{}` to `e`.

For example, instead of `Brunnermeier and Sannikov (2014)`, i would want to display  `Brunnermeier e Sannikov (2014)`. Does someone know a way to change that?

The `babel` package does not translate `natbib`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unfortunately `natbib` does not support localization. You should consider `biblatex`.

Comment: Depending on the bibliography style you use, it can be done: see [Change multiple author reference from '&' to 'and' with natbib bibliography](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/8587) (duplicate). It works with the`agsm` and `dcu` bibliography styles.

Comment: You can also change the `and` quite easily using the `apacite` package, which is also compatible with `natbib`.

Comment: `natbib` doesn't control the language of the "and" conjunction between author names. The form of the conjunction is determined by the bibliography style. Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: I actually migrated to `biblatex` after egreg's comment, but it is nice to know that i could actually do i what i thought before. I had employed the `apalike` style, could you explain to me how i can change the conjunction, please?
Also i'm going to check `apacite`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you would do it using the `apacite` package.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{SchmittMunn2002,
    Author = {Cristina Schmitt and Alan Munn},
    Journal = {Linguistic Variation Yearbook},
    Pages = {185-216},
    Title = {The syntax and semantics of bare arguments in {Brazilian Portuguese}},
    Volume = {2},
    Year = {2002}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\renewcommand\BBAA{e}
\renewcommand\BBAB{e}

\begin{document}

\citet{SchmittMunn2002}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

To do the same thing with the `apalike` bibliography style see:

- [Change citation conjunction from "and" to "i"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109221/2693)