# Replace "and" by "et" using apalike style

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I want to replace the word "**and**" by "**et**" in my document using the apalike package.

MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{apalike} 
\begin{document}
Change this :\cite{1} ... \cite{2}.
Keep this : \cite{3}.
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{sample}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\end{document}
```

My **Sample** file :

```
@article{1,
author =       "H. Suami  and M. F. Scaglionih",
title =        "Anatomy of the Lymphatic System and the Lymphosome Concept with Reference to Lymphedema",
journal =      "Seminars in Plastic Surgery",
volume =       "Volume 32",
number =       "1",
pages =        "5-11",
year =         "2018",
DOI =          ""
}

@book{2,
author    = "R.I.E. Sam and S.E. Boudjellal",
title     = "Étude Rétrospective Du Lymphome Hodgkinien Entre 2006 et 2016 Dans La Région de Constantine",
year      = "2017",
publisher = "Thèse de Master",
address   = "Université des Frères Mentouri Constantine"
}

@book{3,
author    = "J. Diebold and J. Audouin and A. Le Tourneau and T. Molina",
title     = "Pathologie ganglionnaire non tumorale",
year      = "2007",
publisher = "ELSEVIER / MASSON",
address   = ""
}
```

The result :

[image]
[image]

How can I get this changes ?

Comment: You are not using `biblatex`, so I have removed that tag to avoid confusion. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109221/35864 where the procedure is explained for Catalan.

Comment: Would you consider using the `apa` style of `biblatex`?

Comment: @moewe - Nice suggestion, i.e., the reference to the earlier posting [Change citation conjunction from “and” to “i”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109221/5001)! I was going to make the exact same suggestion, including telling the OP that all he/she will have to change in the accepted answer to the earlier posting is to change the replacement conjunction from "i" to "et".