# Changing "and" for "y" in apa (natbib) cite when there are two authors

Tags: citing, apa-style, spanish

When I cite a piece with two authors, LaTeX does something like `(Author1 and Author2, 2018)`. I want to change the "and" to "y", so that the citation call-out becomes something like `(Author1 y Author2)`.

I'm using the `natbib` citation management package and the `apalike` bibliography style, and `babel` for the Spanish language.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Would you consider  loading ``biblatex-apa` instead? This should be automatic with `biblatex`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I could solve it keeping natbib, I have just posted down the answer

Comment: (+1) Fine! Note however customising `biblatex ` is usually much easier than customising a .bst file (it's LaTeX syntax).

Comment: Thanks!, I'll try  biblatex later. How can you write "biblatex" on that way?, I mean inside that gray square

Comment: @Bernard - The steps involved in customizing a bst file can range from the nearly trivial to the nearly infeasible (even for a BibTeX expert...). The complexity really depends on the intended customization. In the case of the OP's query, I'd say the customization complexity is close to trivial -- the more so since the OP located an earlier posting that involved the exact same customization, except for the minor fact that the language-specific conjunction is now `y` rather than `i`.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it!!

The answer is based on the following query: [Change citation conjunction from “and” to “i”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109221/5001)

I copied the system file **apalike.bst** to the file **apaesp.bst**. Then, in the **apaesp.bst** file, I changed all instances of `" and "` to `" y "`. I also changed things like "Technical Report", "In", etc to Spanish.

Finally I modified the `\bibliographystyle` instruction to this:

```
 \bibliographystyle{apaesp}
```