# Bibliography questions

Tags: bibliographies, errors, citing, natbib, jabref

As I write my Bachelor thesis at the moment I tried to teach myself how to use Latex.
But I am struggling a lot with my bibliography as I can not find a way to program it the way I want to:

> Surname, N. und Surname, N. (year), Titel, .... other informarion

(The german word 'und' between the authornames is extremly important)

Sadly I could not find how to do that on the Internet or in other questions.

I recently tried `alphadin` and `apalike`. But with `alphadin` I get only Errors: (Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.) and with `apalike`, with which i can compile my document, it does not look as I want it to. Besides that I always get that `and` between  names, which is not that practical as I write my text in german.

I put all my literature into JabRef.

my Code looks as following:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{acronym}
%\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
%\usepackage{bibgerm}
\usepackage[flushmargin, hang]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
....
%-Literaturverzeichnis--------------------------------------------
%\nocite{*}
%die Verwendung von bibtex ist Pflicht!!!
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\bibliography{Literatur} #so heißt mein JabRef File
%\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystyle{alphadidiEN}
%bzw. unsrtdin, alphadin, abbrvdin

\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%plainnat statt plain
%unsrtnat statt unsrt
%abbrvnat statt abbrv
%alphadidiEN statt alpha,

\newpage
\end{document}
```

Most of the things with the % were given in the orientation file from my university.

I hope you can help me
(and sorry for the trouble with the wrong language at first :) )

Comment: Please note that we expect all posts to be in English on [tex.se]. Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Although some of us are fluent in German (including myself), you should ask your question using the English language. This way you have access to a broader spectrum of answerers and future visitors facing the same problem as you (or a similar one) can benefit from this thread.

Comment: Herzlich willkommen ... Bitte deine Frage auf Englisch umstellen.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Didn´t knew that and changed it now! :)

Comment: Is the only issue you have with the `apalike` bibliography style that is uses `and` instead of `und` as the conjunction. Please advise. And please state which document class you employ.

Comment: Yes apalike uses `and` instead of `und` and I don´t like, that it underlines the titles.  My document class is `\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,titlepage]{article}`

Comment: The underlining of the journal names does *not* come from the `apalike` bibliography style directly. Instead, it comes from the preamble instruction `\usepackage{ulem}`, which changes the method of emphasis from italicizing to underlining. (I suppose that "ulem" is short for "underline for emphasis"...) If you don't want this behavior, either don't load the `ulem` package at all or, alternatively, load it with the option `normalem`, i.e., write `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`.

Comment: Do take a look at the posting [Change citation conjunction from “and” to “i”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109221/5001). That query also employs the `apalike` bibliography style. All you'll need to change in the instructions provided in the main part of the accepted answer is to use `" and "` instead of `" i "` as the replacement text string. Oh, and do call the modified bibliography style file something like `apalike-und.bst`, not `apalike-catalan.bst`.

Comment: Thanks. I found a file called apalike-german.tpm and renamed it into apalike-german.bst but i dont know how to open that into my document and continue with the other steps... (I can not ask this question under the recommended answer posting)

Comment: @Lisa - I just noticed that someone has already created a file called `apalike-german.bst`; see https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apalike-german. If your TeX distribution is up to date, it's probably already installed on your system. Do give `\bibliographystyle{apalike-german}`. a try. As always after changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle`, it's necessary to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Comment: @Lisa - I have no idea what might be in the file `apalike-german.tpm`. (It doesn't seem to be installed on my system.) My hunch is that files with extenion `tpm` are not closely associated with files with extension `bst`.

Comment: `apalike-german.tpm` is a MikTeX file that contains information about the MikTeX package `apalike-german`. It would surprise me greatly if you could just rename that file to `.bst` and could use it. Just use the MikTeX Console to install the package.