# How to change citation conjunction using agsm (harvard style)?

Tags: bibtex, harvard-style

So, I am currently writing using the `agsm` bibliography style to generate Harvard-style (aka authoryear-style) citation call-outs. The problem is that I am writing in swedish and when I want to cite publications with two authors, then `\citep{carlsson2007evidence}` will generate the following "Carlsson and Rooth (2007)". However, I want to replace "and" with "och".

I found a similar question here [Change citation conjunction from "and" to "i"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109221/change-citation-conjunction-from-and-to-i) where the solution is to modify the .bst file in order to change the conjunction but I dont know where I need to modify in the .bst file.

Can someone tell me where I need to modify the .bst file or if there is another solution to the problem?

Comment: With `agsm` it should be enough to redefine the command `\harvardand` in your preamble: `\renewcommand*{\harvardand}{i}` (or `\newcommand*{\harvardand}{i}` depending on whether or not the command is already defined by a package you load). No need to modify the `.bst` file.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. This is my preamble:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[hyphens, spaces, obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % loads the package
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\renewcommand*{\harvardand}{och}

I get an error: \harvardand undefined. Why?

Comment: Right! I used \newcommand*{\harvardand}{och}. It works! Thank you! :)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

The styles of the `harvard` use the macro `\harvardand` for "and". You can (re)define that macro as you see fit. Depending on the package you are using (`natbib` or `harvard`) and where you are issuing the (re)definition, you may have to use `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand`.

```
\newcommand*{\harvardand}{och}
```

or

```
\renewcommand*{\harvardand}{och}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your objective correctly, you want the conjunction used in "text-style" citation call-outs (the call-outs generated by `\citet`) to be "och" and the conjunction used in "parenthetic-style citation call-outs (the call-outs generated by `\citep`) to be `\&`.

The `apacite` bibliography style actually implements exactly this approach. If you're free to switch from `agsm` to `apacite`, all you'd have to do extra is to run the instruction `\renewcommand{\BBAB}{och}`, to switch the conjunction word from "and" to "och".

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{ab:3001,
  author = "A and B",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\renewcommand{\BBAB}{och}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{ab:3001}. \citep{ab:3001}.
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```