# How to change "and" in Bibliography to Icelandic "og" in Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, languages

I´m writting my thesis in icelandic on Overleaf. The English references with more than one authors in the bibliography are automatically with "and" instead of icelandic "og", is it possible to use newcommand or something to change it on Overleaf? see example here:

```
@incollection{wals-36,
  address   = {Leipzig},
  author    = {Michael Daniel and Edith Moravcsik},
  booktitle = {The World Atlas of Language Structures Online},
  editor    = {Matthew S. Dryer and Martin Haspelmath},
  publisher = {Max Planck Institute for Evolutionary Anthropology},
  title     = {The Associative Plural},
  url       = {https://wals.info/chapter/36},
  year      = {2013}
}

Daniel, M. and Moravcsik, E. (2013). The associative plural. In Dryer, M. S. and Haspelmath, M., editors, The World Atlas of Language Structures Online. Max Planck Institute for Evolutionary Anthropology, Leipzig.
```

Here´s beginning of the document(deleted parts which are not related to the question):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\bibliography{heimildir}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This depends on which bibliography package and style you are using. Can you show us a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407), please?

Comment: just added more info :)

Comment: @Xindan Okay, the code you posted shows the `natbib` package, which means you are using BibTeX. However, to change the `and` string we need to know which `\bibliographystyle` you are using.

Comment: Bibliography style is: 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

Comment: @Xindan For apalike there is already an answer [by Mico here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109226/134574). You'll need to modify the `apalike.bst` file, but it's very easy. Follow the instructions there replacing `" and "` by `" og "`. Report back if you have problems :-)

Comment: Thank you! The {apacite} bibliography style worked :) 
On the other hand, it seems that it made the roman numerals from big symbols to small ones, 
e.g. Íslensk tunga ii (which I´d like to have as II instead), how do I change that?

Comment: @Xindan Ooh, actually I meant the first approach (before the “Addendum”). I tried but I couldn't reproduce the uppercase roman numerals you mentioned. Perhaps if you provided a compilable example, then we could fix it. Or try the first approach in Mico's answer. (P.S.: When you are replying to someone use `@<username>` so that they get a notification of your comment.)

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik I couldn´t change the apalike.bst as I´m using online LaTex platform (Overleaf)... can you see this example file?
https://www.overleaf.com/5834573172yvcgtbmtghhx