# How can I change "and" to "e" in apalike bibliography style?

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I'm portuguese and the citation and the bibliografy have to be in portuguese. I want "Afonso, D. e Ribeiro, A. F. (2018)" instead of "Afonso, D. and Ribeiro, A. F.(2018)".

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) to your question so others can reproduce the issue you describe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change citation conjunction from "and" to "i"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109221/change-citation-conjunction-from-and-to-i). The earlier posting was about replacing "and" with "i" -- the Catalan form of "e"; otherwise, the setups of the postings are identical, e.g., they both employ the `apalike` bibliography style. I trust you'll figure out how to adapt the earlier answer to meet your formatting needs.