# Change citation conjunction from "and" to "och" using apalike and natbib in OVERLEAF

Tags: bibtex, natbib, overleaf, apa-style

I am using overleaf, the bibliography style 'apalike' and the usepackage 'natbib'. In the output, the citations use the conjunction "and" between two authors. However, I'm writing in Swedish so I want the conjunction to be "och".

I have seen the other posts regarding this subject, like [Change citation conjunction from "and" to "i"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109221/change-citation-conjunction-from-and-to-i), which seems to discuss the same issue. However, I'm not sure how to incorporate the suggested changes in the overleaf editor.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The webpage you provide a link to contains all the instructions you need. If you can't find the base file `apalike.bst` in Overleaf, you can always grab a [copy](https://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/apalike.bst) from the CTAN. Just rename it to, say, `apalike-och.bst` and proceed from there.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the respons! I'm not sure how to upload or change documents in the overleaf editor. I can't find bst documents anywhere. How do I go about that?

Comment: Did you notice that I provided a link to a copy of `apalike.bst` on the CTAN (Central TeX Archive Network)?

Comment: Overleaf-specific questions (such as how to upload a file to your Overleaf directory) should be directed to the Overleaf Helpdesk. I hear their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand how to upload the document, but how can I override the original apalike.bst with my new file?

Comment: It happens automatically as your folder is searched first. Though it might be better to rename it to `swedish-apalike.bst` and use `swedish-apalike` in your document. Just in case you later on want to write in English and now your `apalike` is in Swedish.

Comment: Solved it, thank you for the file!

Comment: You asked, "how can I override the original apalike.bst with my new file"? It's by following the file-naming instructions given in the link you provided and in the first comment shown above: Give the new bst file a new name, say, `apalike-och.bst` or `swedish-apalike.bst`, or whatever, and then change the argument of `\bibliographystyle` from `apalike` to `apalike-och`, `swedish-apalike`, or whatever.

Comment: It works now, thank you!