# How to change language in citation?

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, citing, german

I am using,

```
bibliographystyle(apalike).
```

when I quote a work from 2 authors it shows up as [AuthorA and Author B, 2023]. I would like to have the "and" in German as "und". I tried using `bibliographystyle(apalike-german)` which did not work. Any tips on how to approach this?

Comment: Does the posting [Change citation conjunction from "and" to "i"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109221/5001) help? The accepted answer [shameless self-citation alert!] deals with adapting the  file `apalike` to Catalan, not German. However, the principles should work just the same.