# Natbib "et" instead of "&" for 2 Author Names

Tags: natbib

i have to use "et" instead of "&" in my article's citations. I am using *Natbib* and *Har2nat*.

> some text  (Author, A. et Author, B.)

but i get just

> some text (Author, A. & Author, B.)

Is there any possibility to do this.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate question. This is already solved here: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19831/natbib-change-author-separation-to](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19831/natbib-change-author-separation-to) or here: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8587/change-multiple-author-reference-from-to-and-with-natbib-bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8587/change-multiple-author-reference-from-to-and-with-natbib-bibliography)